# Url regex that can work without http://, https://

Tags: regex

I am currently using this regex to parse a user's profile text and spit out links:

```
(https?:\/\/|www\.)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)
```

How could this be modified to match common urls without the `http://` `https://`? (or if you have a better regex, that's fine)

e.g. matches:

```
twitch.tv/myusername
youtube.com/myusername
twitter.com/myusername
steamcommunity.com/id/myusername
```

will NOT match:

```
blah.blah
```

For a working example, I noticed Slack has a really good url detector.
[image]

**UPDATE: This one seems closer to what I want but still matches `blah.blah`**

```
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$
```

http://www.regextester.com/?fam=97352

Comment: Have you tried googling this? "url regex detector"

Comment: blah.blah is a valid URI though, it just has a non-existent TLD. If you only want a few TLDs to be accepted, you could hard code those in, but otherwise there's not really a way for a regex to tell that blah.blah is not a real site, while youtube.com is.

Comment: @Chris So that's probably what Slack is doing? Hardcoded common ones like .com .net .co? I'd be alright with that.

Comment: That would be my best guess. Possibly even a comprehensive list of all the TLDs. To put that in your regex, you could replace the `[a-z]{2,5}` with a list of TLDs you want to accept like `(tv|com|net|org)` and so on.

Comment: android has an implementation https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/util/Patterns.java#L323

Comment: Well that will be tough. First of all, nowadays there are tons of TLDs, many of them rather long. currently longest is 24 characters. Another problem is presented by accented domain names, that are doman names containing non ASCII characters, so I don't think it is possible. check www.simulateur-prêt.fr